# How to set a time limit for a Ruby code to run

Tags: ruby

I want find a way to set a time limit on a ruby code so it will exits after that time limit has expired.

Comment: Why not do `Time.new`, do X loops, then check to see if the new time is more than your time limit after the time you started at? Or do you not have control over the function that is taking a long time to run? If so, your possibilities are 1) call it asynchronously, so your code still has control and can just give up after a while 2) write a second process to terminate the first if it takes too long

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm not sure why this question is being downvoted, it is very simple to do with the [timeout](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) module.

This lets you pass a block and a time period. If the block completes within the time period, the value is returned. Otherwise an exception is thrown. Example use:

```
require 'timeout'

def run
  begin
    result = Timeout::timeout(2) do
      sleep(1 + rand(3))
      42
    end
    puts "The result was #{result}"
  rescue Timeout::Error
    puts "the calculation timed out"
  end
end
```

In use:

```
2.0.0p0 :005 > load 'test.rb'
 => true
2.0.0p0 :006 > run
the calculation timed out
 => nil
2.0.0p0 :007 > run
the calculation timed out
 => nil
2.0.0p0 :008 > run
The result was 42
 => nil
```

Comment: Nice! answer. Short but to the point. But one question is why `load`,instead of `require`?

Comment: load is better when testing a script, as require won't reload it after you change it (require tracks what you have already required so the same script isn't required multiple times).

Comment: Any good source to check out the difference between `load` and `require`? Would you refer me?

Comment: @Priti [This](http://ionrails.com/2009/09/19/ruby_require-vs-load-vs-include-vs-extend/) is fairly comprehensive.

Comment: @PuneetGoyal Thank you very much for the link. `+1` to you. That's what I was looking for. :)